# Set terminal color without having bash history look wrong?

Tags: bash, ssh, debian

A site suggested I wrote the below to set the color of my terminal in `~/.bashrc

```
export PS1=`printf "\033[32m$ \033[39m"`
```

If I log in through ssh, press up, home, up text will be garbled.

You can reproduce this by typing "echo abc", close the terminal, log in again and type `ctrl+r abc` . I get `echo abc echo abc` on the screen. I have no problems when I take out that printf out of bashrc. How do I set a color in my terminal or how do I have this so I don't get broken text?

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/a/831973/693277 . And you don't really need `printf`.